# Hosting plugin Google Code with auto update?

Tags: plugins, directory

I've been developing a WordPress plugin for a friend who needs something completely out-of-the-box, at least what WordPress is cornerned. Now, I could use the WordPress plugin repository to host this, but I've already hosted this project on Google Code and was wondering if there was any fancy code which would make WordPress check for updates from that repository.

I feel this plugin isn't really for the general WordPress crowd and don't want to clutter the directory. So I was wondering if this was possible.

Thanks!

Davey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible
take a look at [WPML](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/sitepress-multilingual-cms/trunk/inc/upgrade_plugins.php) to see how its done, also there is an an entire chapter in [Professional WordPress Plugin Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470916222) to show you how its done and [here](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-WordPress-Plugin-Development.productCd-0470916222,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html) is the code that goes with it